# how to check if a verb stem is in a file in python?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a file containing the stems of verbs. I want to give the code a verb and it checks the file and returns the stem of that. for example my verb is "going" and in the file I have the stem "go". I want the code returns "go".
here's my code, but it doesn't work. How should I change it?

```
def stemmer (verb, file):
    with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f:  
        f = f.read().split()
        for i in f:
            if i in verb:
                return i

file = "c:/python342/rootLexicon.txt"
>>> stemmer ("خوردن", file)
'خورد'
```

Comment: Next time, please format yourself properly.

Comment: Are you assigning the returned value to a variable?

Comment: When you say is doesn't work, do you mean it's not showing anything?  If that's the case, then @jgloves is correct ^^

Comment: actually, I'm doing it for persian language. it has out put, but the letters are seperated.

Comment: def stemmer (verb, file):
     with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f:  
          f = f.read().split()
          for i in f:
               if i in verb:
                    return i

Comment: >>> file = "c:/python342/TestWords.txt"
>>> print (stemmer ("قريبه", file))
ه
ب
ر
ق
ر
ب
ه
ق
ر
ب
ب
ر
ر
ه
None

Comment: @sara, could you format your above comment within an edit to your original post? It's difficult to understand inline.

Comment: well, it seems the problem was about my file. and the code is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print(stemmer("going", file))
```